# How to show the continuity of the following map?

Tags: general-topology, homology-cohomology, homotopy-theory

I came across a proof regarding the relationship between the fundamental group and the first singular homology group over $\mathbb{Z}$ and there is a step I wish to clarify a bit.

Let $X$ be a topological space, I have two relative homotopic paths $\gamma \thicksim \gamma'\,\, rel\,\{0,1\}$ via the homotopy $F$, and I'm gonna call $x_0=\gamma(0)=\gamma'(0)$ the starting point and $x_1=\gamma(1)=\gamma'(1)$ the end point.
Now I define the following map:
\begin{align}
     \varphi:\,\, &I\times I \to \Delta_2 \\
     &(s,t)\mapsto (s-st,st)
\end{align}
where $\Delta_2$ is the standard 2-simplex. This map can be restricted to $(0,1]\times I$ giving us the homeomorphism: $\varphi_{|}:= \varphi_{|(0,1]\times I}$. Now the proof define the following new map $\sigma:\Delta_2\to X$ defined as follows:

\begin{equation}
\sigma(s,t):=
\begin{cases}
F\circ(\varphi_{|})^{-1}(s,t) & (s,t)\neq (0,0) \\
x_0 & (s,t)=(0,0)
\end{cases}
\end{equation}
Now, the proof takes for granted the continuity of such $\sigma$, however it doesn't seem so obvious to me so here I am, I tried to prove the contiuity but failed so far.

I know this might be a naive question, but any help is very much appreciated :)

Comment: Try using that $\varphi$ is a quotient map.